# How to use data as array instead of namedtuple

Tags: python

For a preorder traversal on the below hierarchy

```
         1
        / \
       /   \
      /     \
     2       3
    / \     /
   4   5   6
  /       / \
 7       8   9
```

The correct output should look like this:

```
preorder:    1 2 4 7 5 3 6 8 9
```

I have the below snippet for [preorder traversal](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/tree_traversal#Python). I need to have this hierarchy1 as an array and execute the same. How do I do this?

```
from collections import namedtuple
from sys import stdout

Node = namedtuple('Node', 'data, left, right')
hierarchy1 = Node(1,
            Node(2,
                 Node(4,
                      Node(7, None, None),
                 Node(5, None, None)),
                      None),
            Node(3,
                 Node(6,
                      Node(8, None, None),
                      Node(9, None, None)),
                 None))

def printwithspace(i):
    stdout.write("%i " % i)

def preorder(node, visitor = printwithspace):
    if node is not None:
        visitor(node.data)
        preorder(node.left, visitor)
        preorder(node.right, visitor)


stdout.write('  preorder: ')
preorder(hierarchy1)
stdout.write('\n')
```

Comment: Is that the assignment? Store a tree structure as an array? If it is you need to use Heap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, Store the left , right of an element at index i at 2i+1, 2i+2 in an array where i is 0 for root and in case of  Null, store -1 or INF.

Now for the traversal you can traverse to left and right in the same way. But now the left is at 2i+1 and the right is at 2i+2.

So, for example for the tree you have given ,

Suppose there is a list lst which has 20 elements all assigned to -1.

Then `lst[0] = 1.` 
Since at left of 1 which we have 2 so it will be stored at `2*0+1 which is 1.`
Since at right of 1 we have 3, it will be stored at `2*0+2 which is 2.`

Now moving to next index i.e. 1
Since at left of `lst[1]` i.e. 2 , we have 4, so we will store 4 at `2*1+1 which is 3.`
At right of `lst[1]` i.e 2 , we have 5, so we store it at `2*1+2 i.e 4`.

like this we go on storing.

```
lst = []
lst.append(1);
lst.append(2);
lst.append(3);
lst.append(4);
lst.append(5);
lst.append(6);
lst.append(-1);

preorder(lst,0);


def preorder(lst,i) :

    if i > len(lst):
        return;
    if lst[i] == -1:
        return;
    print lst[i];
    preorder(lst,2*i+1);
    preorder(lst,2*i+2);
```

Comment: @realspirituals : Updated my answer with explaination.

Comment: If you need more clarification, do let me know.

Comment: http://algoviz.org/OpenDSA/Books/OpenDSA/html/CompleteTree.html# This can help you

Comment: @realspirituals : I have also put a code, it will help you understand the algo.

Comment: @realspirituals : Does it help you now?